# Find first occurence of a number in each line of a file

Tags: text-processing

Is there any way to capture first occurrence of number in each line from the file.

For example, I have a file called, `test`, and the content is something like

```
AA111 1 DFJKD BKJ3 () A G C TT

BB112 DKFJ 32 JDKFJ JE () DF

113 BDNF 33 3()
```

And desired output is

```
111

112

113
```

Each line in the input starts with alphanumeric characters (i.e. either alphabet or numbers; no special characters)

Comment: do the lines in the file always start with non-numbers, or could you have a line such as `124 junk`?

Comment: Sorry, I should've specified. I editted the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few ways:

```
sed 's/^[^0-9]*\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/' test
```

```
cat test | tr -c '0-9\n' ' ' | while read first rest; do echo $first; done
```

```
gawk -F '[^0-9]+' '{print $2}' test  # requires non-digits to start line
```

```
perl -nE'say/(\d+)/?$1:""' test      # code golf
```

bash:

```
while read line; do [[ $line =~ [[:digit:]]+ ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]} || echo; done
```

Comment: Thanks!! It worked great. I know extra question should be handled in a separate post,but do you know how to get two words in a line instead of one in the output file. For example, instead of 111 \n 112 \n 123, is there a way to obtain 111\t111 \n 112\t112 \n 113\t113?

Comment: Simplest way would be to pipe into `| awk '{print $1 "\t" $1}'`

Comment: Why assume no line *starts* with a number (in the Sed command)?

Comment: Good point. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it in sed:

```
sed -n 's/^[^[:digit:]]*\([[:digit:]]*\).*/\1/; /[[:digit:]]/p' test > test.out
```

This:

1. strips out any potential leading non-digits,
2. captures & replaces (`\1`) the digits and (anything else) with just the digits
3. if the line contains any digits, print it (otherwise, default to `-n` not printing lines)

(hat tip to glenn for encouraging a little compression of my original sed statement)

Answer (score 0):

and with grep:

```
grep -oP '^\D*\K\d+' File
```